# Socket.io not working on https cloudflare

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, socket.io, cloudflare

I'm new on nodejs/socket.io and I've being lost for 2 days now. I have a  app on production running ok on http. I'm trying to configure it to run on https free cloudflare with no succcess. Here is my code:

**serve.js**

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = require('express');
const options = {
//(free CloudFlare certifies are instaleld on cPanel)
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/hostnane.example.com.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/hostnane.example.com.key'),
    requestCert: true,
};
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const { name = 'default', port = '8443'} = args;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

//socket.io stuff

server.listen(+port, 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx', (err) => {
   if (err) {
   console.log(err.stack);
   return;
}
console.log(`Node [${name}] listens on //127.0.0.1:${port}.`);
});
```

**app.js**

```
var socket = io.connect({ query: 'userid='+userOnline});
```

**index.php**

```
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

The script link is loading the homepage of the site. I have tried `xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8443` and `https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8443` won't load.
If I try https://www.example.com:8443 however I can reach my index.html application page, which I suppose indicates Node/Express is working.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Could these be of any help? https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2642 and https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200278659-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed - Was it a 525 error? Could you state in a bit more detail what happens, what errors you get, etc?

Comment: @Matt Fletcher I've hit this thread before, I'm using Full SSL, does it make any sense to create a rule to avoid it for node port? I did a try and it just change the error to 520, which is a still more generic "server unknow error".
I also tried test the connection via curl using the command `curl -vso /dev/null --user-agent "Mozilla 5.0" -H "Host: hostname.example.com" https://example.com:8443` which get connected and find the certificates giving me a 530 erros, which I suppose is a Joomla not logged in response.